# Wrong usage of malloc

Tags: c, malloc

I am trying to use dynamic memory for my code in C. I am using struct and I am doing something wrong, but I can't figure out what. The first part is part of my header(.h) file where I define both of my structs.

The second part is part of my C(.c) file where I initialize the struct and use it. I get a seg fault and ddd tells me that seg. fault occurs in the line after the comment: this is where the seg. fault occurs. 
Any help would be most appreciated

=======================================

first part

=======================================

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <ctype.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>

    void parseFile(FILE * fp, FILE * sketcher); 
    void processArgument(char argument[]);
    void printOutput();
    #define MAX_WORD 256
    #define initial_size 17    
    extern const char argument[];

    FILE* popen(const char*, const char*);

    int pclose(FILE*);

    struct pointxy {

        double x;
        double y;

    };

    struct figure{

        char figureName[MAX_WORD];
        struct pointxy vertices[17];
        int countPoints;

    };

    struct figure figurehere[17];
    struct figure newFigure[17];
```

=======================================

second part

=======================================

```
#include "draw2.h"
#include "draw2a.h"
#include "memwatch.h"

struct figure *figureHere;
void printOutput(){
    printf("./draw2 started on:");

    fflush(stdout);
    system("date\n");
}
/*send what ever there is after the child to sketchpad(in that specific line)*/
void child (char line[], char word[], char nameFigure[], FILE * sketcher){          
    sscanf(line, "%s%s", word, nameFigure);
    fprintf (sketcher, "%s\n", &line[6]);
} 

/*I construct the struct by reading from the Figure line to the end figure line.*/
struct figure* figureFunction (FILE * fp, char line[], char word[], char figureName[], int countNumberoffigures){
    double startx, starty;
    int temp = 1;
    sscanf(line, "%s%s%lf%lf%s", word, figureName, &startx, &starty, word);
    figureHere->vertices[0].x = startx;              
    figureHere->vertices[0].y = starty;
    strcpy(figureHere->figureName, figureName);
    fgets(line, MAX_WORD - 1, fp);                  
    int nuRead = sscanf(line, "%s", word);              
    int i = 1;                                                     
    while (strncmp(word, "End", MAX_WORD)!=0){ 
        if (strncmp(word, "#", MAX_WORD) == 0){
            printf("%s",line);
        }           
        if (strncmp(word, "draw", MAX_WORD) == 0){
            sscanf (line, "%s%lf%lf", word, &startx, &starty);
            figureHere->vertices[i].x = figureHere->vertices[i-1].x + startx;
            figureHere->vertices[i].y = figureHere->vertices[i-1].y + starty;
            i += 1;
        }
        fgets(line, MAX_WORD - 1, fp);
        nuRead = sscanf(line, "%s", word);
    }                                          
    figureHere->countPoints = i;
    return figureHere;                        
}
```

=======================================

third part

=======================================

```
#include "draw2.h"
#include "draw2a.h"
#include "draw2b.h"
#include "memwatch.h" 

struct figure myFigures[17];

struct figure **pointsAndname;                     

const char Exec_c[]  = "java -jar Sketchpad.jar";

void parseFile(FILE * fp, FILE *sketcher){ 
    char line [MAX_WORD], word [MAX_WORD], figureName [MAX_WORD];
    int countNumberoffigures;                                   //accounts to which figure in the array we are on
    printOutput();
    int temp = 1;
    countNumberoffigures = 0;
    while ( fgets(line, MAX_WORD - 1, fp) != NULL ){
        int nuRead = sscanf(line, "%s", word);
        if ( nuRead > 0 ){
            if(strncmp(word, "Figure", MAX_WORD)==0){           //1)reads the figure, name and the two starting points
                countNumberoffigures += 1;                      //accounts to which figure in the array we are on
                pointsAndname = malloc(sizeof(struct figure*)*temp);
                pointsAndname[countNumberoffigures -1] = figureFunction(fp,line, word, figureName, countNumberoffigures);
            }                                                 
            if(strncmp(word, "printFigure", MAX_WORD)==0){      //4)read the command printFigure, name of the figure
                printFigure(fp, line, countNumberoffigures);
            }
            if(strncmp(word, "drawFigure", MAX_WORD)==0){       //5)read the command drawFigure and the name of the figure
                drawFigure(sketcher, line, countNumberoffigures);
            }
            if(strncmp(word, "translate", MAX_WORD)==0){        //6)read the command translate 
                translate(line, sketcher, countNumberoffigures);
            }
            if(strncmp(word, "child", MAX_WORD)==0){            //7)reads command child and the name of the figure
                child(line, word, figureName, sketcher);
            }
            if(strncmp(word, "#", MAX_WORD)==0){                //8)reads the whole line until the \n
                printf(line);
                //printf("ani po\n");
            }
            if(strncmp(word, "end", MAX_WORD)==0){
                fprintf (sketcher, "end\n");
                //printf("ani po\n");
            }
            if(strncmp(word, "rotate", MAX_WORD)==0){
                rotate(line, sketcher, countNumberoffigures);
            }
        }
    }
}

void processArgument(char argument[]){
    FILE *sketcher;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen (argument, "r");
    sketcher = popen(Exec_c, "w");
    if (sketcher == NULL){
        printf ("Could not open pipe to %s\n", argument);
    }else{
      parseFile(fp, sketcher);
        fclose(fp);
        if (pclose(sketcher) == -1){
          fprintf(stderr, "draw_line error: couldn't close pipe to %s.\n", Exec_c);
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

int main (int argc,  char *argv[]){
    int i;
    if ( argc < 2 ){
        printf ("%s\n", "0 comment(s)");
    }else{
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++){
            processArgument(argv[i]);
        }
    }
    //int *a = malloc(sizeof(int));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What line after what comment? Fix your question please.

Comment: I wish I could edit your post to format your code for you, hopefully someone will come along and do it correctly.  That said, I don't even see where `figureHere` is declared. But, if you're segfaulting with its use, you can pretty much bet that it's an uninitialized pointer that's not being assigned properly. Please post the entire code for a guaranteed answer.

Comment: how is `figurehere` defined ? and how it is initialized?

Comment: @KevenK: That looks like the problem, go post the answer now :)

Comment: @KevenK: Sorry if I edit it bad, its just that it's my first time using this site and I am not sure how to enter my code here. I added the rest of the code, hopefully clear that way. Before I was just trying to make the post short.

Comment: @Paul Kar: When adding code, it's best to paste it into the box, then highlight all of it and click the `Code Sample` button in the editor.

Comment: @leppie: I have a comment in the code where I say this is where the seg. fault occurs (so the line after that is responsible for the seg. fault). I am not sure how to use line numbers here. Sorry. :(

Comment: I think I may have cracked the code... :-)

Comment: @Paul Kar.: It was not there originally.

Comment: @leppie: sorry about that. I probably forgot to add it at the beginning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your header file, you're declaring a static array of figures with:

```
struct figure figurehere[17];
```

But in your implementation file (*.c), you are creating a separate pointer to a 'figure' with

```
struct figure *figureHere;
```

Now, technically these are completely independent and both `figurehere` and `figureHere` will be accessible in your implementation file, because C is case-sensitive...but, I imagine this might not be intentional on your part, and at the very last might be considered poor practice because of it's potential to be confusing or misleading when reading the code quickly. I would recommend, if you intend them to be completely separate variables, that you name them more obviously different.

However, what was said in comments earlier *is* the correct answer:  You are declaring a pointer `figureHere`, and using it without ever having initialized it.

....I had written out an explanation under the assumption that you intended for `figureHere` (capital H) to point to `figurehere` (lower H), but then I realized that the question specifically mentions `malloc`. Unfortunately, `malloc` does not even appear in your code, so I am unsure how the use is "wrong" except that there *is no use*. Is code missing, or are you having trouble correctly using `malloc` to create a `figure` for `figureHere` to point to?

---

Edit/Additional:

Re-reading the question I notice you specifically say

> The first part is part of my
>   header(.h) file where I define both of
>   my structs.

This *really* makes me believe that you intended for `figurehere` and `figureHere` to be the same array. To make this happen, you have a few options:

1) Remove `figureHere` and just use `figurehere` directly. Because you have declared `figurehere` as a global here (which many will tell you is bad, but that's a completely different topic), you can access it directly without requiring any pointers.

2) Initialize `figureHere` to point to `figurehere`. You can do this by simply changing your declaration to

`struct figure *figureHere = figurehere;`

Comment: @ KevenK: I am so stupid. I forgot that I moved my malloc to a separate module. I just didn't want to post the whole code because I thought it was to long. I will add the module with the malloc. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Paul Kar: Seeing your latest edit with the additional code, it is important to note that your use of `malloc` is not impacting the *current* seg fault you are generating. See the rest of this answer for information on that. However, your use of `malloc` is in fact incorrect, and will lead to future segfaults if that code ever loops twice. By calling `malloc` and assigning `pointsAndname` to the result, you are gathering new memory. However, on your second pass through that loop, you will point to entirely new memory, and it is very likely (depending on the variables) that ... (Cont'd below)

Comment: ... `countNumberoffigures - 1` will be greater than the length of the new memory you have created with `malloc`, and will then result in undefined behavior and (if you're *lucky*) will crash.

Comment: So my pointsAndname is the array of pointers to the struct. I need to allocate memory for those structs and I thought that I would do it directly by pointsAndname = malloc(sizeof(struct figure*)*temp);
I see what you are saying, but I am not sure how to change my malloc to be correct.